# PHP drop-down list with main item as optgroup and child item as option

Tags: php, database, select, optgroup

I try to create a drop-down list from a database that contains the main items and their child items. I want the main items to become optgroup labels and the child items the option items.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="$rs_pa['Name']">
    <option value="$rs_ch['Link']">$rs_ch['Name']</option>
    <option value="$rs_ch['Link']">$rs_ch['Name']</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="$rs_pa['Name']">
    <option value="$rs_ch['Link']">$rs_ch['Name']</option>
    <option value="$rs_ch['Link']">$rs_ch['Name']</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

The above is just a scheme to show where each variable should fit..

$rs_pa['Name] - is the name of the parent item.

$rs_ch['Name] - is the name of the child item.

$rs_ch['Link'] - is the link of the child item.

This is the code I have right now:

```
$mysql_table_items      = "sys_menu_top";
$mysql_table_options    = "sys_options";

// SQL QUERY
$mysql_result_number    = mysql_query("SELECT VALUE FROM $mysql_table_options WHERE Name LIKE 'nav_menu_elements_on_line_usr'") or die($myQuery . "<br/><br/>" . mysql_error());
$mysql_select_parent    = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table_items WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
$mysql_select_child     = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table_items WHERE `Parent` = '" . $rs_pa['ID'] . "' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order` ASC";

// SQL RESULT
$mysql_result_number    = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_number, MYSQL_ASSOC) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());
$mysql_result_parent    = mysql_query($mysql_select_parent) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());
$mysql_result_child     = mysql_query($mysql_select_child) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());

$output .= "<select>";
while ($rs_pa = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_parent)) {
    $output .= "<optgroup label='" . $rs_pa['Name'] . "'>";
    while ($rs_ch = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_child)) {
        $output .= "<option value='" . $rs_ch['Link'] . "'>" . $rs_ch['Name'] . "</option>";
        }
    $output .= "</optgroup>";
    }

$output .= "</select>";

echo $output;
```

The prblem is that this doesn't show right.. I tried everything but I am not so good with php.. Thank you for any help..

Comment: im sure you don't need 3 queries

Comment: What does your current output look like?  Are all the children showing up under the first parent and that's it?  I don't see how you are not getting errors with the code above.  More specifically with your child query.

Comment: They look like Home (main item) is optgroup then All items main items including home again and childs are options are under the first optgroup (Home) and then All the rest parent items are optgroups..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing to `$rs_pa['ID']` on this line:

```
$mysql_select_child     = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table_items WHERE `Parent` = '" . $rs_pa['ID'] . "' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
```

Are you sure `$rs_pa['ID']` is defined at that point?

Something like this should work better:

```
$mysql_table_items      = "sys_menu_top";
$mysql_table_options    = "sys_options";

// SQL QUERY
$mysql_result_number    = mysql_query("SELECT VALUE FROM $mysql_table_options WHERE Name LIKE 'nav_menu_elements_on_line_usr'") or die($myQuery . "<br/><br/>" . mysql_error());
$mysql_select_parent    = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table_items WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order` ASC";

// SQL RESULT
$mysql_result_number    = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_number, MYSQL_ASSOC) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());
$mysql_result_parent    = mysql_query($mysql_select_parent) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());

$output = "<select>";

while ($rs_pa = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_parent))
{
    $output .= "<optgroup label='" . $rs_pa['Name'] . "'>";

    $mysql_select_child     = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table_items WHERE `Parent` = '" . $rs_pa['ID'] . "' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
    $mysql_result_child     = mysql_query($mysql_select_child) or die("Error: Query Failed! " . mysql_error());

    while ($rs_ch = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result_child))
    {
        $output .= "<option value='" . $rs_ch['Link'] . "'>" . $rs_ch['Name'] . "</option>";
    }

    $output .= "</optgroup>";
}

$output .= "</select>";

echo $output;
```

Some further improvements could be made:

- Stop using `mysql_query` and switch to PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) which is more secure. The `mysql_query` functions are deprecated starting from PHP 5.5.0 anyway.
- Rewrite your query to fetch all the data you need in a single query. This will really speed up things.
- Separate your PHP from your HTML by using templates.